# API working but doesn't return any data?

Tags: api, rest-api

For testing purposes I've setup a REST Guest role with "All" access across the Catalog in my store, so I can throw some queries at the API whilst I find my feet.

Using Simple REST client in Chrome I can issue a GET request to http://www.mystore.co.uk/api/rest/products/1/categories which in theory should return the name of the category(ies) that product ID 1 has assigned to it?

I'm getting a success (200 - OK) response but the only actual *data* I get returned in Simple REST Client is "[[]]" rather then the name of the category that product ID 1 is in.  I've verified that the product definitely has a category assigned.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The request shouldn't give you the name of the category but rather it's id.
The expected resonse should be something like the following JSON (or XML depending on your HTTP request `Accept` header).

`[{"category_id":"3"}]`

The empty response you posted indicates that you didn't assign the *Catalog > Product > Product Category > Read > Category ID*  to the REST Guest Role ACL Attributes Information.

You can set those in the adminhtml backend at
*System > Web Services > REST - Attributes*. Then choose the Guest Role and make the assignment.

Comment: Fixed my problem immediately, thanks @Vinai. There are so many configuration options in M1 that it's hard to work out what's causing something like this.